# How to create unreadable files in linux

Tags: linux

I have a configuration file with me and want to make the file unreadable to others.. What can be done with it?? Encryption is a way to do it.. But Encryption makes the file uninstallable in Linux platform.

Comment: Maybe I am missing what is being asked here.  By the comments it sounds like you are trying to create a configuration file that is shared to others on other systems but is not able to be read by them and at the same time readable by something that doesn't know anything about an encryption algorithm.  If that is the case, this is not possible...At all.  You can control permissions of a file on a particular system as others have noted below, but it isn't possible to have a file that is readable by some and not by others across systems unless you are doing something like public key cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

Change the permissions on the file so that only the owner can read it and that group and all-users (others) can't read/write/execute it.

chmod go-rwx file

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: I want to make it permanent.. So that it can't be changed..

Comment: The file would a .conf file. So it needs to be unreadable and should be able to install also.

Comment: You mean that nobody else can change the permissions? Only the owner and root would be able to do that with this permission setting.

Comment: I'm not following the unreadable part.  The file has to be readable to the process that needs it's configuration information.

Comment: Ya. I mean once it is made unreadable, no one can change it but it should be able to use the code inside it which will be used in the file installation.

Comment: The file should be readable only by the OS and nobody else.

Comment: The OS does not read files, processes (software) do. What user is the process running as. For exapmle, if you "chown auser file" you set the owner to "auser" and if you run the process as "auser" then the process can read the file but no other users (but root).

Comment: You're not going to keep root out.  Root is the system.  The absolute best you can do is make the file readable only by the owner of the file and root.  You can make it harder on root by issuing a chattr +i against the file (as root) which would prevent accidental changes but root can easily disable that and change the perms.

Comment: So by chatter +i filename, will the file be permanently unreadable(except for root)?

Comment: No.  That prevents people from changing the file contents or the permissions on the file.  Either this answer or the one I gave above will make the file only readable by the owner of the file and root.  Who owns the file?  Who owns the process that needs this file for it's config?

Comment: Ultimately, something needs to be able to read the file! You can't have a totally unreadable file otherwise it's pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chmod to see the permissions on the file

```
chmod 600 filename
```

This will make the file readable and writable by only the owner of the file.

Comment: Can it be done permanantly on a file?

Comment: Yes, file permissions are permanent.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the file unreadable by regular users, by changing the file mode (`chmod`) or the file attributes (`chattr`) or file system access control (`setfacl`). But remember, there is NO WAY you can prevent the `root` user from reading the file. The root user will be able to reset what ever restriction you put on the file.